# how to check if array contains empty array?

Tags: php

I have an array like this:

```
array(1) {
    ["trace"]=>
       array(0) {
      }
 }
```

I want check if `trace` is empty or not, if I do this:

```
if(!empty($contents['trace']))
{
   echo "not empty";
}
```

the `echo` is printend but shouldn't. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if(array_filter($array['trace']))
{
   echo "not empty";
}
else{
 echo "empty";
}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `count()` with `isset()`:

```
if(isset($contents["trace"]) && count($contents["trace"])>0){
    echo "not empty";
} else {
    echo "empty";
}
```

The reason to use them both is because if you *only* use `count()` but the array is not set, it will throw an error. Using `isset()` as a condition will mean that the `count()` condition will only be checked if the array actually exists.

---

*Reference*:

- PHP: count - http://php.net/manual/en/function.count.php
- PHP: isset - http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php

Answer (score 1):

You can count the array using `count()`

```
if(count($contents["trace"]) > 0){
    echo "Array is not empty.";
} else {
    echo "Array is empty.";
}
```

More information on `count()` at http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_array_count.asp.